# JqueryDataTable not maintaing page number after a refresh

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using Jquery Data table to display some information(Grid is having merged rows). Data is being loaded from a json variable.

It is working fine as expected.  There is a requirment to add new row to the existing grid. I have added the data to the json variable and reloaded again.

Its working as expected. Grid is having pagination.

But the issue is, when reloading is happening from pages 2, it comes back to 1st page after data load.

I tried to use below codes,but it is not working.

```js
bStateSave": true,
        "fnStateSave": function (oSettings, oData) {
            localStorage.setItem( 'DataTables_'+window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(oData) );
        },
        "fnStateLoad": function (oSettings) {
            return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('DataTables_'+window.location.pathname) );
        }
```

Also tried with draw(false), but no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You only need the `stateSave: true` do you not? as seen here https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html

Comment: i tried this, but it is not working

Comment: State saving applies to when you reload the page (i.e. not to re-drawing the datatable, if that is what your logic does). A minimal reproducible example would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for this. Thank you all for your comments.

I checked if it is a refresh or first load

```js
var pgIndx = '';
        if (newRow)
         pgIndx = $('#TableId').DataTable().page();
         
         var tables = $('#TableId').DataTable({}).draw(false);
 if (newRow)
            $('#TableId').DataTable().page(pgIndx).draw(false);
```